# Sierra 10.12.3 sed:can't read... error

Tags: macos, sed

I can't understand why my old script previously ok, didn't work today.

myscript.sh:

```
...
export LC_CTYPE=C
export LANG=C

# Delete all lignes begining by ' "Doc '
sed -i "" '/^"Docteur /d' $1
...
```

When I run `./myscript.sh myfiletotreat.csv` I get this message:

```
sed: can't read /^"Docteur /d: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like the macOS's default BSD implementation of `sed` is being shadowed by _GNU_ `sed`, whose `-i` syntax differs, which causes the error you're seeing. Try explicitly with `/usr/bin/sed`.

Comment: As an aside: To make sure your script also works with filenames that contain characters with special meaning to the shell, such as spaces, you should replace `$1` with `"$1"`.

Comment: Great ! That's working again. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's native *BSD* `sed` implementation (that macOS comes with) was being shadowed by a later *GNU* `sed` installation, whose `-i` syntax differs, causing the error cited.

Invoking the native BSD `sed` with `/usr/bin/sed` is a quick workaround, but the better approach is not to shadow native utilities at all.